# How to generate EC X509 certificate on unix?

Tags: unix, ssl, x509certificate, elliptic-curve

I need to generate X509 certificate using EC.

What are the commands that I need to perform in order to achieve a `PEM` file of this certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a private key with the elliptic curve of your choice:

```
openssl ecparam -name <curve> -param_enc explicit -genkey -out key.pem
```

You can find all supported curves with `openssl ecparam -list_curves`.

Afterwards you can create your certificate request, e.g.:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -key key.pem -out certificate.pem
```